# Dynamic Data Masking not applying for unprivileged users on Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to configure [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dynamic-data-masking-get-started) on Azure SQL Server.

However however I apply the mask, an unprivileged user still has access to the unmasked data even when though they should not have permission. As sanity check I tried the same setup on a SQL Express local database installation and encountered no issues.

I am using the following script:

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS 'Current database version';
GO

--Create a table Cars with masked tables for License plates and the names of the owner.
CREATE TABLE Cars (
    id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    LicensePlate nvarchar(20) MASKED WITH(FUNCTION = 'partial(1, "****", 1)') NOT NULL,
    OwnerName nvarchar(40) MASKED WITH(FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL
)
GO

-- Add some dummy queryable data
INSERT INTO Cars(LicensePlate, OwnerName) 
VALUES ('AAA111', 'Alice'), ('BBB222', 'Bob'),
       ('CCC333', 'Carol'), ('ABC123', 'David'),
       ('XYZ987', 'Emily')
GO

-- Look at all the data in plain form(as admin user)
SELECT * FROM Cars
GO

-- Create a regular user who has no privileges
CREATE USER regular_user WITHOUT LOGIN
GRANT SELECT ON Cars TO regular_user;

--Execute the same select query as the regular user and see nothing
EXECUTE AS USER = 'regular_user'
SELECT * FROM Cars
REVERT
```

Result on Azure database:

[image: Result on Azure Database]

Result on local database:

[image: Result on local database]

According to Microsoft the feature should have general availability and it does seem like the Azure portal picks up on the configuration. But unprivileged users can continue to query unmasked data only in the case of Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by Microsoft support. I have contacted them they helped resolve the issue as it was deeper than anything configured by making a new server and new database.

From the official response:

> The reason is because at server level masking feature was set to disable by Product group to mitigate  an issue related to  “Data classification” and “ Masking”  when both were enabled. This configuration has been changed at server level, and now you will be able to create and mask databases located  on this server.

After some more smaller issues with Data Masking not working I was asked to run the following query:

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION CLEAR PROCEDURE_CACHE;
```

This clears the query plan cache and makes sure unmasked queries are cleaned from the cache.

If any other users are experiencing similar issues, I'd recommend taking this up with Microsoft support. It could help to point towards this answer as to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new feature (in preview) called Data Discovery & Classification, which has the potential to cause this phenomenon, of DDM not properly masking content for an unprivileged user. If you've enabled this on the same DB server, that likely explains the issue.
This, by the way, likely also explains why masking on your other DB works as expected.
The fix for this is on the way - just a matter of getting fully deployed.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the compatibility level of the database to 140.

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name   
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL =  140;
```

On Azure you are running on compatibility level 12 that is similar to SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I have performed this action but this doesn't seem to have changed anything, Azure SQL still reports the same version and masking is still not working.

I am wondering if this could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157966/dynamic-data-masks-stopped-working?rq=1

Comment: Let me try to get an answer and come back to you.

Comment: Good day Tich, (1) The @@VERSION is not the same as the  Compatibility level. @@VERSION is an instance version that you use (version of the server if you want), while the Compatibility level is a database level parameter. In order to get the Compatibility level of the database you can execute the query "SELECT compatibility_level, name FROM sys.databases". (2) Even if you use COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120 on SQL Server version 2017 (@@VERSION = 14...) the DDM should work! You can test it on local database as well... Must start new comment to add more info (I really hate stackoverflow interface)

Comment: Compatibility level provides only partial backward compatibility. You can create new database in SQL Server 2017 -> confirm compatibility_level = 140 -> change COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120 -> confirm COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120 -> connect to the new database and execute your script with DDM. It should work

Comment: I have escalated the issue by opening support ticket with Azure support. After trying an existing database, it worked there. Which leaves me even more puzzled. Trying to get a clear answer from Microsoft support.

Comment: Please read the answer provided by Rohit (user7453088) above. She belongs to Microsoft team.